# Texture painting without rendering vertex paint

Tags: vertex-colors, texture-painting

I need to apply a texture paint to a mesh that already has vertex colors attached to it:
[image: Vertex paint mode]

When I want to draw on this mesh in texture paint mode the vertex colors get applied too:
[image: Texture paint mode: The vertex colors obstruct most of the mesh]

As you can see, the vertex colors make it hard to see anything of the texture paint in the dark areas.
How do I disable the vertex colors during texture painting?

As a less important side question: How do I disable lighting as well?

I just want the pure texture to be displayed during painting.

Comment: You can enable *Shadeless* in your material to remove the shading.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to GLSL shading and enable *Shadeless* in your material settings:

[image]

With GLSL enabled in texture paint mode, *wireframe* view will display only the vertex colors, *solid* will display both, and *textured* will display only the textures.